# Google analytics track multiple custom variables

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm tring to use google analytics to monitor activities on my laravel site, as you can see i managed to record the events by `$user_name` witch is great however how to i associate this user name with another variable for example `$project_id` so i can see data for each user and on each different project.

[image]

any idea how i can achieve this? here is my code:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).mousemove(function(){

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-9YXX', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension<Index>': 'user_id'}
});

gtag('event', 'user_name', {'user_id': '{!!$user_name!!}'});

});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the gtag directly from your codebase. This will inevitably increase your technical debt as well as clutter your code. It's better conducted directly from GTM.

Also, you're mixing up things... Events are supposed to represent certain actions or states. So the idea is to generate events on key activities and then fill them with data you need to pass. You do it differently: you generate an event whenever you need to pass data, so now your events are pretty much meaningless, you only use them as containers for dimensions. That will be a problem later on.

Another issue there is... are you sending an event on every mousemove? Just to indicate user id? There are these things in GA4 called user-level dimensions/properties. You should look at them and set them with pageviews rather than wasting events and cluttering your analytics and your users' network traffic.

Now finally, we've got to your question. You can send several properties with your events. You can see that the last argument of your gtag() call is an object. Well, use it:

```
gtag('event', 'user_name', {
    'user_id': '{!!$user_name!!}', 
    'project_id': '{!!$project_id!!}'
});
```

It's odd it didn't occur to you to try it.

Comment: gtag also uses the datalayer (in fact it is a wrapper for the datalayer; it is not surprising that two products by Google use similar infrastructure), so I think your first paragraph should be rephrased or removed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and giving a very comprehensive explanation, i have tried this but the "Users by User property" is still only showing "user_id"

Comment: first, did you add the project id dimension to the report? And second, did you wait for two days for the data to become available? And three, did you inspect the network calls to make sure project id is being set?

Comment: @BNazaruk yes i have the exact same code running for few months and when checking the realtime status all i get is "user_id" and in the report "project_id" is there but it is all equal to (not set) see image here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rjoa.png

Comment: Inspect the call in the network tab.

Comment: @BNazaruk i can see in the network tab https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejHNK.png but it's nowt showing in the status, see photo

Comment: Perfect. Did you actually create that event property in the GA config? And is it of the same level as your user_name property?

Comment: @BNazaruk is this what you are referring to? https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2TBl.png

Comment: @BNazaruk or is it this https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2gdr.png

Comment: Ooooh, you have the dimension created AND it has traffic! Sorry, this completely changes the issue. Your issue is with the custom reports UI. I've had many issues with it reporting nonsense too, but try making a new tab there and only have events as a metric and your two dimensions as dimensions in the report.

Comment: @BNazaruk i just did and it shows only "0", i thought my issue was with sending the data

Comment: no, it looks to me like your data tracking is fine. It seems like a GA4 interface issue. Try shuffling dimensions and metrics, changing what's a row and what's a column. GA4 attempts to copy AA, but does so very poorly. It's still full of bugs. We're recommending people not to use it for a while. Like give it another year or two to mature. Google is being unreasonably pushy with a bugged product.

Comment: @BNazaruk i understand, thanks again for taking the time